# react-native-svg align items in a radius view

Tags: react-native, svg, skia, react-native-svg

I'm creating analog watch in react native with react-native-svg. I've managed to create the watch but I'm having issues with aligning the watch numbers to the hour marker and make the space even between the markers and numbers. Here's an example

[clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z43AC.png)

Here's my code for creating the hour marks and the watch numbers

```
  {/* Hour marks */}
    {Array.from({ length: 12 }).map((_, index) => {
      const angle = (index * Math.PI * 2) / 12;
      const x1 = radius + Math.sin(angle) * (radius - verticalScale(20));
      const y1 = radius - Math.cos(angle) * (radius - verticalScale(20));
      const x2 = radius + Math.sin(angle) * radius;
      const y2 = radius - Math.cos(angle) * radius;

      return (
        <Line
          key={`hour-mark-${index}`}
          x1={x1}
          y1={y1}
          x2={x2}
          y2={y2}
          stroke={'#BEBEBE'}
          strokeWidth={2}
        />
      );
    })}

    {/* Numbers */}
    {Array.from({ length: 12 }).map((_, index) => {
      const angle = ((index + 1) * Math.PI * 2) / 12;
      const x = center + Math.sin(angle) * (center - verticalScale(40));
      const y = center - Math.cos(angle) * (center - verticalScale(50));

      return (
        <SvgText
          key={`number-${index}`}
          x={x}
          y={y}
          fill={'#515151'}
          fontSize={`${verticalScale(29)}`}
          textAnchor='middle'
        >
          {index + 1}
        </SvgText>
      );
    })}
```

[Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/y2DfMsDUJ)